# Cygwin and PHP Executable

Tags: cygwin

In Windows, using Cygwin: How can I get the shebang line in a shell file to load the PHP interpreter?
I am using the **prggmr** library.

By default, in the **shell** file this is what I have

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

And it works if I type this into **Cygwin**:

```
php c:/path/to/file
```

I have PHP and this Library setup in my **environment paths** so I can just type **prggmr**. So by typing "prggmr" it should work, but i keep getting

```
/cygdrive/c/lib/prggmr/bin/prggmr: /cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3: 
bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I have tried these with no luck, the same error as above:

```
#!/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3
#!/cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your Paths right you have a Win32 PHP installed that you want to use with PHP. Normally, I'd say don't do it this way as things are going to get confused. Better to install PHP in Cygwin directly imo. There are a few resources out there, check out
[this one](http://smehome.net/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&id=67%3ainstall-php-and-apache-on-cygwin) for a good starting point.